# Android service in Chat App Crashes

Tags: java, android, tcp, client, chat

Hi i have a chat app that communicate with a Tcp server and I am trying to use Service so the app will still be connected to the server when i close it.

after i start the Service the app is connecting and it works but when the app is closed and the server sends a message to the app, it crashes.
i use AsyncTask and here is my code

The Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    new MainActivity.connectTask().execute("");




    return mStartMode;
}
```

The task

```
 public static class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        MainActivity.mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                /*
                */
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });

        MainActivity.mTcpClient.run();



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Communication.ManageData(values[0]);

    }
}
```

and

```
public class Communication extends Activity {
public static TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(MainActivity.cpn);
public static ArrayList<String> dipattern = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> forconfirm;

public static void ManageData(String data) {

    dispatternFunc(data,dipattern);

    switch (dipattern.get(0)) {
        case "100":

            tinydb.putBoolean("isLoged", true);


            Intent intent = new Intent("finish_activity");
            MainActivity.cpn.sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;

        case "101":


            break;

        case "103":


            break;

        case "104":


            break;

        case "106":


            break;

        case "200":
            String temp = dipattern.get(2);

            if( In_Chat.mAdapter2!=null)
            {
                In_Chat.mAdapter2.addMessage(temp, 0);

            }
            else
            {
                ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatData = tinydb.getListString(dipattern.get(1));
                ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatDirection = tinydb.getListInt(dipattern.get(1) + "d");


                ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatData.add(temp);
                ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatDirection.add(0);

            }
            tinydb.putListString(dipattern.get(1), ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatData);
            tinydb.putListInt(dipattern.get(1) + "d", ChatCustomAdapter.AllChatDirection);

            String confirm;
            forconfirm = new ArrayList<String>();

            forconfirm.add(User.username);
            forconfirm.add(dipattern.get(1));
            confirm = Communication.pattern(forconfirm, 201);

            //sends the message to the server
            if (MainActivity.mTcpClient != null) {

                MainActivity.mTcpClient.sendMessage(confirm);
            }



            break;

        case "201":


            break;


        case "202":


            break;

        case "300":


            break;

        case "600":


            break;

        case "601":


            break;

        case "602":
            TabFragmment2.fAdapter.addUser(dipattern.get(1));
            TabFragmment2.fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            tinydb.putListString("myFriends", FriendCustomAdapter.FrListItems);


            break;

        case "603":


            break;

        case "604":


            break;

        case "900":
            TabFragment1.mAdapter.addUser(dipattern.get(1));
            MainActivity.tempnum++;
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
            TabFragment1.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            tinydb.putListString("myUsers", MyCustomAdapter.mListItems);
            break;

        case "911":
            break;

        default:



    }

    dipattern.clear();


}
```

The app crashes when i closed it and i get message "200" for Example

i get this error

```
02-22 15:40:06.194 5550-5550/com.example.user.loco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.user.loco, PID: 5550
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.example.user.loco.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:249)
at com.example.user.loco.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:220)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:671)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:375)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:370)
at com.example.user.loco.TinyDB.<init>(TinyDB.java:51)
at com.example.user.loco.Communication.<clinit>(Communication.java:12)
at com.example.user.loco.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:249) 
at com.example.user.loco.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:220) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:671) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please add code of `TinyDB` class

Comment: i took tinydb from here https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb

Comment: It doesn't have `TinyDB.java`.

Comment: please don´t post Your complete project, it´s too much to go through Your complete code. Post only the relevant part of, where the error occurs...

Comment: if the app is closed you cant send a message from service to the app

Comment: I am not sending a message I am receiving. and when the app is closed the service is connecting to the server  and the onprogress function is called so why when i get a message it crashes?